Why do I need and/or want a CancellationToken for my Azure ServiceBus message?
I'm trying to understand what the CancellationToken is used for and if I need to use it?
If I have this code below, I can cancel it by calling CancelScheduledMessageAsync so what is a cancellationtoken for? The link here is pretty obscure
ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queue);
ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(messageBody);
var sequenceNumber = await sender.ScheduleMessageAsync(message, scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc);

// now cancel
ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queue);
await sender.CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber);


It's to cancel the ScheduleMessageAsync asynchronous operation before the await continuation runs.

that doesn't make any sense to me. Why would I call scheduleMessage and cancel it immediately with a cancellationtoken?

(At least) three possible reasons come to mind: first, in the context of ASP.NET, because the incoming HTTP request itself was canceled (CancellationToken is bound to the HttpContext.RequestAborted); second, in a user-interactive (i.e. deskop UI program) it'd be sensible to always allow the user to cancel any current asynchronous operation; third, because you want to set a maximum timeout (say, 30 seconds) in case the ScheduleMessageAsync method hangs or gets stuck.

...fourth: because your ServiceBus activity happens in the context of a distributed transaction and you get a transaction cancellation request while the ScheduleMessageAsync method awaits.

All service operations are governed by the TryTimeout in the ServiceBusClient retry policy.  This means that every call from every client spawned from the ServiceBusClient instance uses the same operation timeout.  Further, that timeout is applied to each implicit retry attempt made by the client, which are not visible to the application.
In some application scenarios, it is desired to constrain the timeout on a specific operation or call to achieve the application's goals.  For example, consider a receiver that exists to route messages which can be either transient shoulder-tap notifications that are not interesting after a short time or durable commands that always need to be processed to maintain data integrity.
private async Task ProcessMessage(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
{    
    if (message.ApplicationProperties["category"] == "shoulder-tap")
    {
        // We only care about shoulder-tap notifications for 30 seconds.
        // If we can't forward with enough time to process downstream, 
        // just discard the message.
     
        using var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource(
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

        try
        {
            await _notificationSender.SendAsync(
                new ServiceBusMessage(message),
                cancellationSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Expected behavior.  Do not allow the 
            // exception to bubble so that the caller
            // completes the message.

            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Send to the system responsible for processing
        // commands.  If this call fails, we want retries
        // to kick in and any exception should bubble back
        // to the caller so that the message is abandoned and
        // replayed.

        await _commandSender.SendMessageAsync(
            new ServiceBusMessage(message));
    }
}

